# How can I use Bokeh's gridplot to display time series data from a csv-file with automatic updates?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, bokeh

I'm tring to display data from an updating csv-file with bokeh. First column in the csv is consecutive numbers, second column is a timestamp in format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ZZZ (where ZZZ is milliseconds, e.g. 2021-07-30 15:46:17.838). I want to display the values in  columns 3 and follwing over the timestamp.
I tried the following code, but get  the error:

> ValueError: Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into a grid

Here is my code:

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Create a Tkinter root window
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Open the file dialog to select the CSV file
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

# Read the initial data from the selected CSV file
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";")
# Extract the column names and units
columns = data.columns[1:]
units = data.iloc[1].tolist()[1:]

# Create a dictionary to store the line plots and data sources
line_plots = {}
data_sources = {}

# Create a figure for each value column
for column, unit in zip(columns, units):
    p = figure(title=f"{column} ({unit})", x_axis_label="Time", y_axis_label=column)
   # Create a data source for each value column
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))
    data_sources[column] = source
    # Create a line plot for each value column
    line_plots[column] = p.line(x="x", y="y", source=source)

# Define a function to update the plots
def update_plots():
    # Read the latest data from the selected CSV file
    latest_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";")
    # skip first line
    latest_data = latest_data.iloc[1:]
    #Convert the timestamp column to a proper datetime format
    latest_data["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(latest_data["timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    # Update the data sources for each value column
    for column in columns:
        data_sources[column].data = dict(x=latest_data["timestamp"], y=latest_data[column])

# Update the plots periodically
update_interval = 1000  # in milliseconds
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_plots, update_interval)
# Create a grid layout to display all the plots
grid = gridplot(list(line_plots.values()), ncols=1)
# Add the grid layout to the current document
curdoc().add_root(grid)

# Show the plots in a browser
curdoc().title = "Real-time Plots"
curdoc().theme = "light"
```

and here is an example csv-file:

```
number;timestamp;Output;Process
n;t;km;bar
1;2021-07-30 15:46:17.838;30.9832572937;18105.2871094
2;2021-07-30 15:46:17.923;30.9832572937;18105.2871094
3;2021-07-30 15:46:18.000;30.9824104309;18105.2871094
4;2021-07-30 15:46:18.073;30.9815711975;18105.2871094
5;2021-07-30 15:46:18.145;30.9584617615;18139.6484375
6;2021-07-30 15:46:18.230;30.9573440552;18139.6484375
7;2021-07-30 15:46:18.315;30.9573440552;18139.6484375
8;2021-07-30 15:46:18.396;30.9345474243;18173.1035156
9;2021-07-30 15:46:18.469;30.9331626892;18173.1035156
10;2021-07-30 15:46:18.551;30.9317760468;18173.1035156
11;2021-07-30 15:46:18.636;30.9092998505;18205.65625
12;2021-07-30 15:46:18.719;30.9092998505;18205.65625
13;2021-07-30 15:46:18.792;30.9076538086;18205.65625
14;2021-07-30 15:46:18.865;30.8855018616;18237.3046875
15;2021-07-30 15:46:18.947;30.8836021423;18237.3046875
16;2021-07-30 15:46:19.033;30.8817024231;18237.3046875
17;2021-07-30 15:46:19.116;30.8817024231;18237.3046875
18;2021-07-30 15:46:19.189;30.8598823547;18268.0488281
19;2021-07-30 15:46:19.262;30.8577365875;18268.0488281
20;2021-07-30 15:46:19.346;30.837430954;18296.078125
21;2021-07-30 15:46:19.431;30.835062027;18296.078125
22;2021-07-30 15:46:19.508;30.835062027;18296.078125
23;2021-07-30 15:46:19.581;30.8326950073;18296.078125
24;2021-07-30 15:46:19.659;30.8133354187;18322.3007812
25;2021-07-30 15:46:19.744;30.810754776;18322.3007812
26;2021-07-30 15:46:19.827;30.7923545837;18346.7148438
27;2021-07-30 15:46:19.902;30.7923545837;18346.7148438
28;2021-07-30 15:46:19.975;30.7895812988;18346.7148438
29;2021-07-30 15:46:20.053;30.7868099213;18346.7148438
30;2021-07-30 15:46:20.138;30.7682151794;18371.1289062
31;2021-07-30 15:46:20.221;30.7682151794;18371.1289062
32;2021-07-30 15:46:20.296;30.765247345;18371.1289062
33;2021-07-30 15:46:20.369;30.7476272583;18393.734375
34;2021-07-30 15:46:20.453;30.7444801331;18393.734375
35;2021-07-30 15:46:20.538;30.7413272858;18393.734375
36;2021-07-30 15:46:20.619;30.7413272858;18393.734375
37;2021-07-30 15:46:20.692;30.7235298157;18416.3398438
38;2021-07-30 15:46:20.764;30.7201976776;18416.3398438
39;2021-07-30 15:46:20.849;30.7033920288;18437.1386719
40;2021-07-30 15:46:20.934;30.6998977661;18437.1386719
41;2021-07-30 15:46:21.009;30.6998977661;18437.1386719
42;2021-07-30 15:46:21.082;30.6963977814;18437.1386719
43;2021-07-30 15:46:21.154;30.6800098419;18457.03125
44;2021-07-30 15:46:21.239;30.6763553619;18457.03125
45;2021-07-30 15:46:21.324;30.6763553619;18457.03125
46;2021-07-30 15:46:21.399;30.6609745026;18475.1152344
47;2021-07-30 15:46:21.472;30.6571788788;18475.1152344
48;2021-07-30 15:46:21.548;30.6434192657;18490.4863281
49;2021-07-30 15:46:21.633;30.6394939423;18490.4863281
50;2021-07-30 15:46:21.716;30.6394939423;18490.4863281
```

program is started from command line with:

> bokeh serve --show name_of_python_file.py

I tried to modify line_plots to be defined as layout and further changing the format of the values to float, but without success.